# How To Display Specific Amount in Spinner?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, spinner, android-spinner

I want to get information using `putExtra()` on another page and I can do it, but my only problem is always the default value the first value sample_array but i want to by default classDayIntent value is displayed in spinner

tip: The `putExtra()` received in `Spinner` is there

#### First Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.putExtra("className" , className);
intent.putExtra("uniName" , uniName);
intent.putExtra("classDay" , classDay);

intent.setClass(context , AddNewClass.class);

context.startActivity(intent);
```

#### Second Activity:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerDay);

String className = getIntent().getStringExtra("className");
String uniName = getIntent().getStringExtra("uniName");
String classDayInent = getIntent().getStringExtra("classDay"); // How To Display classDayInent In Spinner....

className_EditeText.setText(className);
uniName_EditeText.setText(uniName);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this , R.array.sample_array , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String classDay = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

#### Strings:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">ClassManager</string>
<string-array name="sample_array">
    <item>شنبه</item>
    <item>یکشنبه</item>
    <item>دوشنبه</item>
    <item>سه شنبه</item>
    <item>چهارشنبه</item>
    <item>پنجشنبه</item>
    <item>جمعه</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found correct answer :

```
String classDayInent = getIntent().getStringExtra("classDay"); 

 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sample_array)));

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        //find classDayIntent from List For get Position To Display

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            if (classDayIntent.equals(list.get(i)))
            {
                spinner.setSelection(i);
            }
        }

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            classDay = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


        }
    });
```

Comment: `but my only problem is that I want to put one of the information in Spinner but I do not know how to do it` you didn't specify that you already have it in array

Comment: Because I'm sure it is in array , But there are ways to distinguish it that I did not use

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`add`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add(T)) function of adapter.
since `CharSequence` is an `interface`, and the `String` class implements `CharSequence` so you can directly add string to adapter

```
adapter.add(classDayInent);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

Another issue is , `createFromResources` creates a immutable list mean it cannot add more items.

Solution : create your own adapter with mutable list

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sample_array)));

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
list.add(0,classDayIntent);// to add received element at first position to display
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: do you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: this way have error and application has stopped , There is no way to display it without adding to Array?

Comment: wait, I know the issue, due to array size, let me update answer , meanwhile , post the exception msg for confirmation

Comment: this way work but don't resolve my problem , The amount that is to be received is in sample_array so it should not be added , I'm looking for a way to show it temporarily (as long as I'm on this page)

Comment: `as long as I'm on this page` what do you mean by that and it is no where mentioned in your question see, `but my only problem is that I want to put one of the information in Spinner but I do not know how to do it`

Comment: I'm sorry, my English is weak and I could not ask my question right (I will change my question).

Comment: My main question is, the amount of classDayIntent that is received is in sample_array . I want to by default  classDayIntent value is displayed in spinner , but always the default value  the first value sample_array

Comment: use `list.add(0,classDayIntent);`

Comment: i find new way : spinner.setSelection(position);  to display default , Now how can I compare sample_array with the list to find out the position

Comment: your question was unclear and it's a old way, I didn't recommend because u didn't mention that you already have that item in your array, I would recommend to frame the question properly to avoid confusion in future

Answer (score 0):

You can get your xml arraylist and then add to that:

```
List<String> ar = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sample_array)));
    ar.add("test");
```

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh updated. Yes `Arrays.asList` gives fixed size arrays, so needed to do the trick.

Comment: yup, that's why I mentioned about the issue but still you need to change the adapter construction